# Getting same values when duplicating a reactive form

Tags: reactjs, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am new to angular and I have followed a tutorial to create a reactive form in which I have an input and if I click a button, this input is duplicated.

The front looks like this:

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <form [formGroup]="becDonorsForm">
        <div formArrayName="bec_donors">
          <div class="row" *ngFor="let item of becDonors.controls; let becDonorsIndex=index" [formGroupName]="becDonorsIndex">

          <div class="col-md-2">
            <fieldset>
              <legend style="font-size:12px;">ph:donor id</legend>
              <input type="text" pInputText  style="width:100%"  formControlName="becDonorId" />
            </fieldset>
          </div>
          <div  class="col-md-1">
            <button pButton type="button" (click)="addbecDonorID()"  icon="pi pi-plus" iconPos="center" style="margin-bottom:1px;"></button>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="becDonorsIndex>0" class="col-md-1">
            <button pButton type="button" icon="pi pi-minus" iconPos="center" style="margin-bottom:1px;" (click)="deletebecDonorID(becDonorsIndex)"></button>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Basically I have an input with a button to add another one (duplicate it) and another button to delete it in case it's not the only one.

This is the backend:

```
becDonorsForm: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit(): void
  {  
    this.becDonorsForm = this.fb.group({
      bec_donors: this.fb.array([this.fb.group({becDonorId:''})]),
    })   
  }  
  addbecDonorID() {
    this.becDonors.push(this.fb.group({becDonorId:''}));
  }
  deletebecDonorID(index) {
    this.becDonors.removeAt(index);
  }
  get becDonors() {
    return this.becDonorsForm.get('bec_donors') as FormArray;
  }
```

And up to here everything is great, it works as expected, the problem is that I tried to extend it by adding a select, as follows:

```
      <form [formGroup]="becDonorsForm">
        <div formArrayName="bec_donors">
          <div class="row" *ngFor="let item of becDonors.controls; let becDonorsIndex=index" [formGroupName]="becDonorsIndex">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <fieldset>


<--This-->
              <legend style="font-size:12px;">ph:BECS</legend>
              <ng-container style="min-width: 100%;" *ngIf="localSystemBECS">
                <p-dropdown styleClass="w-100"   [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [options]="localSystemBECS.localSystem" [(ngModel)]="selectedBEC" optionLabel="name"></p-dropdown>
              </ng-container>
            </fieldset>
          </div>



          <div class="col-md-2">
            <fieldset>
              <legend style="font-size:12px;">ph:donor id</legend>
              <input type="text" pInputText  style="width:100%"  formControlName="becDonorId" />
            </fieldset>
          </div>
          <div  class="col-md-1">
            <button pButton type="button" (click)="addbecDonorID()"  icon="pi pi-plus" iconPos="center" style="margin-bottom:1px;"></button>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="becDonorsIndex>0" class="col-md-1">
            <button pButton type="button" icon="pi pi-minus" iconPos="center" style="margin-bottom:1px;" (click)="deletebecDonorID(becDonorsIndex)"></button>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

On the back, I did not add anything other than

```
localSystemBECS : LocalSystemsBECSResponse;
selectedBEC: LocalSystemElement;
```

And a method that fills the first data array.

I guess I have to do something similar to what I already have from

```
   bec_donors: this.fb.array([this.fb.group({becDonorId:''})])
```

but I don't know how to expand it, I would appreciate your help

Comment: I guess because [(ngModel)] and the selectedBEC variable is not in the bec_donors array

Comment: You can try moving selectBEC to bec_donors array and use formControlName instead